# How to select closest bucket to user's position before uploading files Firebase Storage ? (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase Storage for one of my projects to upload files worldwide.
I have a Blaze plan that allows me to create multiple buckets.

I would like to know how can I use the `FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: "the_right_bucket_url")` method in my Flutter app to upload files to the closest bucket to the user's location to minimize latency.

Of course i am asking the permission to get the user's location for other features in my app and i can use it when allowed.
The use case is when i have a permission denied for this.

Is there another way to know where the device requests come from and select the right bucket ?

Thanks in advance